# How to leave a div 100% height in bootstrap smoothly with scroll?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, height

I have a problem.

Can someone explain me or find a solution to the height 100%

I'm making a website using the bootstrap and would like to make three vertical blocks, so when I put height: 100% and min-height: 100% it works, but when the content exceeds the height of the body, it activates the scroll, so far so good, but the column is not 100% height.

```
html, body { margin:0; height: 100%;}
div { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; }
```

See example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOgvjZ

Comment: all 3 of your `.col` elements are the same `height` - are you curious about the white space in the `.col-md-3` element? (that caused by your `margin-top` of your `h1` element`)

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

div { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; overflow:hidden;}

(The new style is the overflow part) or set thew overflow to scroll (overflow: scroll;).

If you set it to hidden, then the extra content will not be visible, is you set it to scroll the each column will have its own scroll bar.

Comment: Yes, but I want to scroll and the fixed background (with height 100%)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; overflow:auto;}
```

`overflow:auto`:  Auto will only show a scrollbar when any content is clipped.

`overflow:scroll`: Scroll will however always show the scrollbar even if all content fits and you cant scroll it.